# How to remove entire redis hashset in minimum time

Tags: memory, redis, time-complexity, jedis, reddison

To delete an entire HashSet Redis we use

> **HDEL key field [field ...]**

where **field** indicates the field which we want to delete in the HashSet.

The above operation takes O(N) time, where N is the number of fields.

Can't we just remove the HashSet Reference i.e. **key** in the above-given command? 
Would that be the correct way to remove an entire HashSet in Redis? If not, why?

Answer (score 3):

You can use **del key**, it works with any data type including hset